# Can matrix multiplication preserves the sign?

Tags: matrices

Suppose I have a maxtrix $X$ and its elements follows a standard Gaussian distribution. Now I want another matrix $W$ to multiply with $X$ to get $Y=WX$, such that signs of $X$ and $Y$ are element-wise the same, i.e.$Y_{i,j}*W_{i,j} \geq 0$. Moreover, I hope the absolute value of elements look different between $X$ and $Y$ except their sign.

I want a sufficient condition, or more easily, a feasible way to construct such $W$. What requirements of $W$ are needed to satisfy the sign preservation?

Comment: By continuity of matrix multiplication, if $X$ is an $n{\times}n$ real matrix, and $W$  is an $n{\times}n$ real matrix which is element-wise sufficiently close to the $n{\times}n$ identity matrix, then $Y$ will have element-wise the same signs as $X$.

Comment: I see your point. But this is similar to the identity matrix $W$.  :)

Comment: If $X$ is a nonsingular $n{\times}n$ real matrix, you can take _any_ $n{\times}n$ real matrix $Y$ which has element-wise the same signs as $X$, and then just let $W=YX^{-1}$.